# Illegal character in path at index 43: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20200122-WA0002.mp4

Tags: android, kotlin

Here am trying to attach the files in my application from the android device. I can able to attach the local files like my camera files and my external card files. but not able to attach the files from Whatapp folder files and download folder files.

```
if(item?.itemId == com.cipherloc.securemailapp.R.id.compose_attachment_button){
   setupPermissions()
} 
private fun setupPermissions() {
        val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

        val permission1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || permission1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            makeRequest()
            Log.i("", "Permission to record denied")
        }
        else{
            filePicker()
        }
    }

My Filepicker Method:

    fun filePicker(){

           var mimetypes  = arrayOf(
            "application/*",
            "audio/*",
            "font/*",
            "image/*",
            "message/*",
            "model/*",
            "multipart/*",
            "text/*",
            "video/*"
            )
            var chooseFile = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            chooseFile.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
            chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            chooseFile.type = "*/*"
            chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
            chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file")
            startActivityForResult(chooseFile, 0)
        }
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,
                                                grantResults: IntArray) {
            val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

            val permission1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

            if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || permission1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                Log.i("", "Permission to record denied")
            }
            else{
                filePicker()
            }
        }
MakeRequest Method:        
            private fun makeRequest() {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    RECORD_REQUEST_CODE)
            }


While Attaching the files from WhatsApp folder files and download folder file am getting error in the below code only.

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {    
        if(data != null) {    
            val uri: Uri? = data!!.data
            val src: String? = uri!!.getPath()  
            val sourceVal = File(src)
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(sourceVal)
            val juri: java.net.URI =
                java.net.URI(RealPathUtil.getRealPath(this, uri))    
            source = File(juri.getPath());
            filesArr.add(source!!)    
            attachmentRecycler?.adapter = attachmentAdapter    
            attachmentAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
            System.out.println("dyhtgfgdas " + source + " " + source!!.length())
        }    
    }
```

Below code is my Error while am trying to attach the files:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.cipherloc.securemailapp, PID: 11885
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/video/media/211985 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.cipherloc.securemailapp/com.cipherloc.securemailapp.ComposeMailFragment}: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 43: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20200122-WA0002.mp4
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4741)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4783)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7212)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:956)
>        Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 43: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20200122-WA0002.mp4
>           at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2892)
>           at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3065)
>           at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3149)
>           at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3107)
>           at java.net.URI.(URI.java:583)
>           at com.cipherloc.securemailapp.ComposeMailFragment.onActivityResult(ComposeMailFragment.kt:1002)
>           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7743)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4734)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4783) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7212) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:956) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11885 SIG: 9
>   Process 11885 terminated.

Comment: Please post the log in a block to make it readable.

Comment: Nice try but wrong block as the lines are not conserved and all is still unreadable. Put it in a block like you used for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL (`/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20200122-WA0002.mp4`) is not URL encoded and fails validation when you try to create a java.net.URI.

It's not really obvious what your code is trying to achieve, but if you just need to construct a valid java.net.URI - pass it through URLEncoder.encode() first:

`java.net.URI(URLEncoder.encode("Your-URI-String", "utf-8"))`

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Jorgen. But how do i get exact path from this Encoder url. KIndly help!